# "Copying" someone else's comment for an answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-user

This is similar but different to [this question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/is-it-bad-form-to-answer-a-question-using-someone-elses-previous-comments). I am often reading through current questions and, as I am trying to think of an answer see a helpful hint in the comments.

Is it unethical to base an answer on someone else's comment?

There are a couple of cases to consider here: sometimes a short comment might be as short as "use MVT," and that is enough to trigger the rest of the answer for me. In this case, my intuition says that the answer is "mostly" my own work. I would probably post as myself and begin with "as ____ said above, we can use the MVT... ." In this case, it can even be difficult to know if I thought of the idea first or got it from the comments.

Other times someone posts an idea but isn't sure how to finish. If I see where they are going and can finish the answer for them, who gets credit?

In the most extreme case, someone basically posts a full answer as a comment, in which case the consensus seems to be to post as community if you want to answer.

---

What are peoples' thoughts on this? I suppose these might just require context. On the one hand, we can err on the side of not taking undue credit and just post as community. On the other, if it feels like you come up with "most" of the answer, should you just take the credit?

---

Note: to distinguish from the linked question, I am *not* referring to the case where an old question has no answers but a partial answer in the comments.

Comment: There might be a reason why someone posts a hint as a comment instead of posting a full answer, namely, to encourage OP to get the answer and to post it as an answer herself. If you step in and post a complete answer, it's not so much a question of taking undue credit, as of depriving the questioner of the experience of working out the answer on her own, from the hint.

Comment: By the way, if someone wants to base an answer on my earlier comment, I will not consider it unethical.

Comment: I have received criticism (almost always from the original asker) before for posting relatively strong hints and sketches as answers. I know most answerers understand that we aren't supposed to be doing anyones homework, but there have been askers who have frustrated me with the other outlook. If I have the suspicion that a poster is not going to appreciate my answer, I would rather just post it as a comment and have it be less likely for them to engage me further.

Comment: @PVAL, opinions differ as to whether posting a *question* that is homework-like is beneficial, but the principle that users should be free to *answer* as they wish was never considered any less important than the ability of voters to hit the up/down/close/reopen/delete buttons in whatever way they like.  In particular, there has never been the idea that  "we aren't supposed to answer homework questions", and users who harrass others for posting answers are engaging in abuse.

Comment: @zyx Sorry I think you misunderstood me. I meant when I merely gave a hint instead of doing someones work I have been pestered by someone (usually the asker) into writing down a complete proof and "doing their homework for them". My comment about the answerers just meant while I think most active contributers (say commenting on meta) will understand my views in this, I don't trust that the average question asker will always (especially if the question itself shows significant misunderstanding of the material and even the question being asked).

Comment: I was really just trying to explain my reasons to post something which many (including myself) would construe as an answer as a comment.

Comment: It sounds like you meant "answerers understand that we aren't *obligated*" to do homework (or anything else),  which is certainly true, as is your observation about OPs.  In the posted wording it seemed that the assertion was "we are supposed [to not]" answer particular questions and my response was to that.  Your reasons for posting comments are perfectly understandable.  My view is that a question "gets what it gets" and that even the most meager reply is fine, by definition.  @PVAL

Comment: I hate it when I post a hint in a comment, and someone posts an answer based on that hint before the OP even has a chance to react... if you figure out the solution to a question after reading a hint, enjoy it. And in particular, give the OP the chance to figure out the problem himself and feel the same enjoyment.

Comment: I wouldn't mind anybody basing their answers on my comments either, long as it's either a verbatim quote or a substantial expansion of it. Botching or misinterpreting my comment is a different can of worms, however.

Comment: Yes, maybe "only hint wanted" question modes or styles could be a thing. "Please give me a map, but I would like to search for the treasure on my own."

Answer (score 18):

Comment-answers are not answers. The system doesn't treat them as answers, no reputation gain is possible, it is not possible for others to upvote *[edit: whoops, you can upvote a comment; but it's not quite the same]*, downvote, correct, edit, or otherwise directly engage with a comment.

If a user posts a complete answer as a comment, then that user has mis-used a comment. It is much more common for a user to post an incomplete answer as a comment. Then it is not bad for someone else to come along, flesh out the content and write a complete answer.

Sometimes, users believe in hinting or helping the OP along, and view this as an educational opportunity for the OP. There is short-term value in *not* expanding these comments into answers assuming the OP is willing to engage with the commenter. But these questions and answers have very little long-term value. Indeed, one of the common failings of online fora is for someone to search and find incomplete threads.

Whether you choose to shortcut the hinters is ultimately up to you. In the overall StackExchange mentality, it is in fact definitely encouraged for you to provide good, complete answers whenever possible. But the Math.SE culture is a bit different, and worth thinking about.

I sometimes expand comments into answers. But I rarely do it on any question that was recently asked. One annoying thing is that unanswered questions are routinely brought back to the front page automatically by the system, in order that they might receive an answer. This is not good when the question is already answered! This fills the front page with somewhat uninteresting content and kicks other, more relevant questions, off the front page.

If I see a question that has been brought back to the front page, but has an answer in a comment, I provide an answer whenever I am capable.

Comment: "it is not possible for others to upvote [...] a comment" Are you sure about that? :-)

Comment: You're right! You can definitely upvote comments. I suppose I consider the culture around comment upvoting so totally different than question and answer upvoting that it doesn't come immediately to mind. But the sentiment remains the same.

Comment: The point was of course tangential. That said, I do not feel that the culture around comment upvoting is much different.

Comment: I agree with this except for some of the value words. I would have said "one of the common **features** of online fora is for someone to search and find incomplete threads"; I do not regard that as a failure. Long-term value need outweigh the short term benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Comments are adequately credited by words like "as stated in the comments by user $U$ ... ".   The CW mode has its disadvantages, and not everyone will want to use it.

It makes sense for authors to decide their use of CW based on whether they want to give more users the ability to edit the answer.  CW has beneficial applications such as answers that require regular updates.

Avoiding reputation gains through CW is an ineffective form of posturing (it suggests at the same time that one *does* care about reputation on non-CW posts).  It would be better to limit use of CW to intended use cases such as compiled lists, where giving more users edit capability has a good chance to improve an answer.

Comment: What are the disadvantages of CW mode?

Comment: More users able to make unwanted edits on the answer, and more users feeling "invited" to alter the answer.  After some edit wars on CW answers I had posted, I stopped using CW.  @joriki

Comment: I've posted plenty of CW answers to lift comments into answers and don't remember ever encountering such problems.

Comment: I still disagree with the "posturing" part of your answer. Not wanting to appear as if one might be trying to gain from the work of others is not necessarily posturing. (I also don't see how it suggests that one does care about reputation on non-CW posts, since caring about looking like a free-rider is different from caring about reputations points. (Not that I disapprove of caring about reputations points.))

Comment: Visibly disassociating one's behavior from some other alternative (and there are only two alternatives here, CW and non-CW) is an assertion of moral superiority relative to the people who choose the alternative, or will be read as that by a large fraction of the audience.  The point of doing it visibly is the assumption that many in the audience consider the alternative behavior to be negative.  Having the gesture be visible constitutes an acceptance and promotion of the negative interpretation, so the moral posturing becomes part of it whether or not the author intends to posture.  @jori

Comment: That's my opinion, anyway, and it would not be uninteresting to have a side discussion of "posturing". The point I consider more important is that use of CW should not be described as something required or as superior to the alternative.  It is an option for the user to choose. @joriki

Comment: I don't see how to make sense of the notion of posturing without intending to posture (unless you mean that the intent to posture is subconscious). What you describe as posturing without intent, I would describe as taking the subjective view of those who would adopt the negative interpretation seriously independent of whether I share it. I don't want to be seen as someone who tries to get reputation cheaply, neither for my own sake nor for that of the site. Whether those who might see me that way are right to do so is less important to me than it seems to be to you.

Comment: Do you agree that "use of CW should not be described as something required or as superior to the alternative. It is an option for the user to choose."?  This seems to me to be the primary point.  I did not  understand (syntactically) the last sentence in your comment, or what "get reputation ... for the sake of the site" could mean. @joriki

Comment: It seems to me that we have quite a different approach to these things, which we may not be able to sort out in a few comments back and forth. To my mind, whether use of CW is better is partly an empirical question that depends on things like how people perceive it, whereas I get the impression that to you it seems to be more of an objective question and if people have a different perception they should be opposed rather than accommodated.

Comment: My question was not whether CW *is* better in some practical or empirical sense, but whether it is acceptable to pressure users (before or after the fact) about the choice of CW or non-CW.    The position that this application of CW is "required or [morally] superior to the alternative" is a form of pressure that I think should not be used on the site.  I do not see any implication of *oppositionality* in the idea that using an option provided by the site should be a free and unpressured choice left to the users.  The answer says only that "not everyone will want to use" CW: it is optional. @j

Comment: That's the first time you're using the word "pressure" in this thread. I certainly agree that it would be bad to pressure users to use CW -- to me, that's pretty far from anything we've been considering here. If I find (partly empirically) that using CW is better, I may say so in certain contexts (e.g. in threads such as this one) -- that's what I understand "describe it as superior" to mean. That doesn't mean that I approve of pressuring people.

Comment: The part about "opposed rather than accommodated" referred to this comment of yours: "Having the gesture be visible constitutes an acceptance and promotion of the negative interpretation, so the moral posturing becomes part of it whether or not the author intends to posture." I interpreted that to mean that one shouldn't accept the negative interpretation, but oppose it.

Comment: "The point I consider more important is that use of CW should not be described as something required or as superior to the alternative" Is this symmetric? That is does it hold for use replaced by non-use? If so, how is this compatible with you passing judgments on it in OP?

Comment: Yes, it is quite symmetrical.  The OP's question stated that there is a certain consensus or requirement to use CW, and this answer points out that the opposite opinion exists and the opposite behavior (vs what was recommended) is acceptable.  And just as a non-CW answer will be interpreted by many as an attempt to grab Stackexchange reputation points, a CW answer will be interpreted by many as a form of moral posturing.  @quid

Comment: I'm using the word *pressure* because the less blunt phrasing of the same question, that did not use that word but only the idea, had not received a response.  I prefer the original wording but the intent is the same.   You might also be interested in the comments below the question where the words *harrass* and *abuse* were used to describe a special case of the same phenomenon.  @joriki

Comment: That alleged symmetry is between very different things. The people who may interpret non-CW answers as an attempt to grab reputation points aren't taking part in this discussion. For the purposes of this discussion, their attitudes are an empirical fact. Your interpretation as moral posturing, by contrast, is *your* interpretation, that you could change right now if you wanted to. No-one here is accusing you of trying to grab reputation points, but you're accusing me of posturing. There's no symmetry there.

Comment: The symmetrical empirical fact (or one I claim to be a fact; see vote counts for some supporting evidence) is that a significant fraction of people reading the CW comment-conversions may be prone to interpret them as having an element of moral posturing.   You're right, nobody using un-CW (or advocating that) was personally accused -- here and now -- of "grabbing reputation points"; the arguments for CW were neutral phrases about "integrity of the reputation system", "being a respectful member of the community", and "not taking undue credit".  Pure empirical practical analytic stuff. @joriki

Comment: "err on the side of not taking undue credit" doesn't say "people who post non-CW are taking undue credit". It's implicit in "erring" that things are complicated and need to be weighed. You didn't write "err on the side of avoiding moral posturing". The other two quotes are from an answer I deleted after commenting "Sorry if I went too far in judging" and "you're right, I hadn't thought it through properly". I wish you'd complete the symmetry by drawing a similar conclusion about the posturing remark.

Comment: @joriki,  1. the remarks from you and the OP are absolutely typical (in the form I quoted, without any additional context) of many similar comments on the main and meta sites on the same subject. It's that context I address.   2. You say that I judge you and others as morally posturing, but have never contended with the full text of *my* remark on that in the answer.  The statement was, CW is ineffective as a posture of "I am not so base as to be motivated by the gain of a few reputation points" because using it is very strongly correlated with the same user taking reputation rather seriously.

Comment: I gathered some empirical data -- I searched for community wiki answers I posted, introduced by "Community wiki answer to allow the question to be marked as answered:" or similar remarks. I found $7$; none of them has a downvote; four have no upvotes; two have one upvote; one has two upvotes. I didn't encounter any evidence of anyone disapproving or interpreting it as moral posturing.

Comment: I did respond to that: "I also don't see how it suggests that one does care about reputation on non-CW posts, since caring about looking like a free-rider is different from caring about reputations points." If you found empirically that it strongly correlates, it may well be that some people are posturing. But the remark in the answer isn't phrased as an empirical finding; it makes a statement about what it is in general, which in its generality necessarily also applies to me. You say I "accuse" you of judging me -- would you not consider calling my behaviour "moral posturing" a judgement?

Comment: I meant votes on this answer, which is the only place I know where words like "moral posturing" are connected to an up/downvote button.  Your deleted answer had the opposite vote pattern, but was only up for a short time and was intermixed with the issue of not crediting the author of the comment, so is harder to interpret.

Comment: It does not only point out the opinion exists, rather it documents it by voicing the opinion quite vehemently. That's a difference. "[...]is an assertion of moral superiority relative to the people who choose the alternative[...]"  Maybe they just want to allow more users to edit? It could make sense in this situation since such answers are often still terse.

Comment: @quid, To make sure I understand the algorithm, for future reference: the presence in an answer of one (relatively calm) word that you and at least one other user dispute qualifies it for classification as a *quite vehement* opinionized diatribe. Is that correct?  Incidentally, you misread the sentence.  Allowing more users to edit was the proposed use for CW in this answer, and someone who followed that suggestion would not be using CW to "avoid reputation gain".  The discussion into which you have now waded was about the use of CW when its purpose *does* include avoiding reputation gains.

Comment: The point is not the wording but that you repeat your point multiple times. To "point out the opinion exists" the first paragraph would have been sufficient. On the sentence, my point is that the behavior your criticize is compatible with the use-case you promote. It is not quite clear which actual practical problem you want to solve.

Comment: There are 6 sentences in the answer, none of them duplicating the others.  The first paragraph names a procedure (somewhat independent of CW) and then poses it as an alternative to CW, but does not give any reasons.  The second paragraph gives reasons to use CW in some situations.  And the third paragraph, some reasons to avoiding CW in other situations.  That seems quite non-repetitive.  The material you objected to appeared in (one word of) one sentence, so it seems actually impossible to have repeated that.   The practical problem solution is in the first sentence.  Satisfied? @quid

Comment: Your penultimate sentence seems unrelated to what I wrote. I was asking you what practical problem related to the (non-)use of CW you want to solve. You seem to blow up a problem for the sake of  complaining about it. As far as I am concerned, It is pretty irrelevant if CW is used or not, and I doubt most users even routinely check the status of posts. I guess I just do not understand you concern about this pretty trivial matter.

Comment: Again for future reference: is the algorithm now that all users who post answers need to justify to @quid the significance and nontrivial importance of their (otherwise declared "pretty trivial") material?  The OP asked *Is it unethical to base an answer on someone else's comment* and related that to (non)CW.  The first sentence of this answer directly replies to the main question, by pointing out that the issue of credit can be handled through attribution.  The rest addresses some reasons to use and not use CW, distinct from credit assignment.  Sounds legal to me.  Is it?

Comment: @joriki, the discussion has been interesting but a bit exhausting.  I will be busy for a while and can try to reply again when I have a chance.  For now I just want to mention that I checked dictionary.com and the definition of "posturing" there exactly fits what I meant; I think you may be taking the word to have additional pejorative associations such as pretending or "phony posturing".  Also that Revision 1 of the answer has a different wording that you might prefer. The word "guessing" there refers to guessing what other people might imagine one's attitude to reputation could be.

Comment: From your reaction I get the impression you in fact  understood by now the inherently contradictory nature of your contribution to this thread. I will not continue the side-show.

Comment: No, I don't prefer that other wording; it also includes "posturing" and in addition "charade". I'd bet against high odds that a survey would find that most people take "posturing" to have pejorative associations. If you didn't intend any pejorative associations, you could simply replace it, if only because it has pejorative associations for me. I'm not sure which of the many definitions at dictionary.com you mean; one of them is "an affected or unnatural attitude".

Comment: I did intend some negative associations, but not the kind that you seem to be associating with the word.  I consider it a negative aspect of the site that posters of certain types of answers feel the need to accomodate (with CW) a potentially hostile audience that might otherwise be likely to brand them as reputation-collectors.  The social signaling process that takes place in such postings does involve some affectation and unnatural behavior, as well as communicating to an in-group that one has the correct in-group values.    @joriki

Comment: Something I missed in this discussion just occurred to me in writing a CW answer: You're right that *upvotes* can be selectively given based on whether the upvoter considers lifting the comment a valuable service to the community (if the fact that the answer is a lifted comment is clearly marked); but the $15$ points for the answer being accepted can't be avoided. Since the entire point of the answer is to be accepted so the question will be marked as answered, one unavoidably intends to gain $15$ reputation points by making the answer non-CW.

Comment: The dictionary.com definition of posturing that I had in mind was no.13 of http://dictionary.com/browse/posturing?s=t , though 12 that you quoted, and 11, also are pertinent. "13.   To act in an affected or artificial manner, as to create a certain impression".  The definition of charade there (http://dictionary.com/browse/charade?s=t ) also applies rather exactly to the CW reputation avoidance ritual  : "a game in which the players ...  act out in pantomime a word, phrase, title, etc., which [others] must guess."   @joriki

Answer (score 5):

I deleted my earlier answer because it was unduly judgemental and not thought through properly. After a long exchange of comments under zyx's answer, I do want to provide an alternative answer again now because I still disagree with zyx's answer.

It appears that there are different attitudes to using CW for lifting comments into answers. Good reasons have been offered both for and against this practice, and no-one who does or doesn't follow it should be accused of trying to gain points off the work of others or of moral posturing.

My personal opinion, based on my personal experience, remains that the downside of CW posts being easier to edit is not very relevant in this case, as this has never happened to any of the comments I've lifted using CW, and that using CW is preferable to make sure that no-one gets the impression that reputation is being unduly collected. That doesn't imply that someone who prefers not to use CW is in fact unduly collecting reputation.

Comment: I stated a very clear position that "the principle that users should be free to answer as they wish was never considered any less important than the ability [to vote freely] .... **users who harrass others for posting answers are engaging in abuse**", and other variations on that theme in my answer, in the comments below it, and in numerous previous threads on this meta.

Comment: Given that this goes beyond the position in your first two paragraphs, I don't know what disagreement you consider this answer to be expressing. You appear to be saying that posting an opinion on meta about a general practice in the abstract, is equivalent to individualized harrassment that might inspire fear in answer-posters. I believe that the number of CW answers that have been criticized as "posturing" (or something akin to that) on the main site is approximately 0.0000, and I do not see much potential for my answer to inspire more cases. What then, is this answer contesting?

Comment: On the other hand, the fear of "giving the wrong impression" by posting non-CW is very real, as demonstrated by your answers and comments in this thread.   So while the principle of freedom to post is symmetrical between CW and non-CW, fear of posting only exists in connection with one of those two options, and that was what led to my answer.

Comment: @zyx: The disagreement I'm expressing lies in "no-one [...] should be accused of [...] moral posturing". Since my extensive attempts at convincing you to reformulate that part of your answer failed, I expressed my disagreement in an answer of my own. I wasn't implying anything about how often such accusations are leveled on the main site; I'm merely disagreeing with you leveling them here.